# JSON subreport problems; data not showing up in main report (jaspersoft studio)

Tags: json, jasper-reports, subreport

I have spent multiple hours on this seemingly simple task. I have a main report which has a subreport, when previewing both reports separately they both populate from the data in the JSON. However when in the main report, the subreport does not show up at all. I have tried all the solutions that I can find on the web, every single one doesn't seem to help me!

My main report :

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="408" uuid="3b7fa906-9011-4ed6-ae8e-0e642de110f7"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("user.documentList")]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\Owen\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\TestFolder\\testsub4.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

My subreport :

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testsub4" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ea880075-0207-45c9-a804-e8cf6d2068d4">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter (6)"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[user.documentList]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="documentType" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="documentType"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[documentType]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="116" y="0" width="114" height="30" uuid="4b456a4d-257e-48fe-b8c6-e209b7cb0f39">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="dc387bf3-e169-4fbe-8c4f-f259ba6b5b75"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{documentType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I believe it must be my data source expression that is the culprit, however I don't know how to fix it.

I am at a complete loss as to what I am doing wrong. If anyone could help I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks :)

EDIT: All complete additional files as requested -

Main Report -

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TestSubreports" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3ce1a4ad-43ca-4058-8018-3cf61497fc13">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="JsonDataAdapterTest.xml"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter (4)"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\Owen\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\TestFolder\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[user]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="firstName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[firstName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="lastName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lastName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="email" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="email"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[email]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="userStatus" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="userStatus"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[userStatus]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="documentList" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="documentList"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[documentList]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="141" height="30" uuid="8f49a338-3eed-4534-8bf2-d82072f66a59"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="141" y="0" width="138" height="30" uuid="ae04e6e9-db4d-4359-a474-d95a355b4cce"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="279" y="0" width="138" height="30" uuid="f2bc475f-a74f-409c-a83c-73edb6136852"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{email}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="417" y="0" width="138" height="30" uuid="d05cc670-5634-43f5-9e8b-9afe18f9f6d4"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{userStatus}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="408" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="555" height="398" uuid="3f4fc8a1-d7ff-40ae-b8b3-c5685bf0948e"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"testsub6.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Subreport -

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testsub6" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="13acf49e-4913-4d1b-bccc-113817ad15d1">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="JsonDataAdapterTest.xml"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter (7)"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[user.documentList]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="id"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[id]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="documentType" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="documentType"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[documentType]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="documentStatus" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="documentStatus"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[documentStatus]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="rejectReason" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="rejectReason"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[rejectReason]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="comment" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="comment"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[comment]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="events" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="events"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[events]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="id1" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Column" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="documentType1" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Column" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{documentType}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="documentStatus1" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Column" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{documentStatus}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="rejectReason1" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Column" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{rejectReason}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="comment1" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Column" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{comment}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="132" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="456" y="0" width="99" height="132" uuid="97705585-a0b5-4ec7-86f3-ae10c220e6af"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["cherry.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="451" height="95" backcolor="#000000" uuid="6c6ca4e1-17cd-4913-93d6-5e670ea9ae8a"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="Title" x="0" y="0" width="370" height="66" uuid="a2a2cac8-5a7d-4487-8c54-dab235ce4e21"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Cherry Title]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement style="SubTitle" x="157" y="66" width="249" height="29" uuid="8978eac3-c578-41c9-837e-48d2b0184642"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="22" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Cherry SubTitle]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="100" width="451" height="32" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CC0000" uuid="e3c14156-5b51-4201-918b-97fdc012e5d4"/>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement x="307" y="12" width="144" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="5c3301e7-a737-4c59-8a2f-a6c79fd1adb8"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="148" y="11" width="100" height="30" uuid="eaa79550-007b-4f6d-a939-62b6057255b9"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="1ab61080-0512-4c3b-be9e-d7231186d148"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="111" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="40a8d166-cee2-499e-ab3e-7d8875276590"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{documentType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="222" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="a03ecea5-b1bc-4928-b961-2e494b6be050"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{documentStatus}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="333" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="5ddeb63e-607d-4906-8b9d-4e1f4dacdf17"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{rejectReason}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="444" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="5d83bd3d-d5c7-4b10-a162-9e49249733f7"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{comment}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="7" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="3" width="555" height="1" uuid="1133a906-5b71-476e-9f3e-bc97c97058c1"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="1" width="555" height="24" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#000000" uuid="729c3539-f946-4d0e-a0a7-bda2815ea1b0"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="513" y="0" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="4834e99c-7f6c-485a-b098-50e5187f2ab4"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="433" y="0" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="9825b46e-76f1-469a-abb8-a1cc27aad685"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="2" y="1" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="137d38c7-1a83-4fc5-b156-9d5f1b1a0ddc"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Json file -

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "firstName": "Mike",
      "lastName": "Jones",
      "email": "mikeJones@gmail.com",
      "userStatus": "VALIDATED",
      "documentList": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "documentType": "DRIVING_LICENSE",
          "documentStatus": "APPROVED",
          "comment": "",
          "events": [
            {
              "action": "APPROVE",
              "comment": "",
              "createDate": "2018-05-24T10:44:55.987+0000"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "documentType": "PASSPORT",
          "documentStatus": "APPROVED",
          "comment": "",
          "events": [
            {
              "action": "APPROVE",
              "comment": "",
              "createDate": "2018-05-24T10:44:55.901+0000"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Post all the code, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Use empty query string in subreport jrxml. You already pass the data from main report.

Comment: @Narcis In subreport: `<queryString language="json">
  <![CDATA[]]>
 </queryString>` Is that what you mean as an 'empty query string'? If so, I still am having the same issue unfortunately as well as there being no fields to enter in the subreport, with a "Document is empty" error. Sorry if I'm not understanding you correctly, I'm completely new to this.

Comment: Please post complete relevant sample files: main report, subreport, JSON data

Comment: Added all files :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reports work fine as they are, in the sense that they compile and display the data. Most likely, you did not recompile the subreport after modifying it. You can either:

- right-click on the subreport JRXML in the `Project Explorer View` and select `Compile Report`
- click on the compile button in the report `Design` tab:
  [image]
- select `Project` -> `Build Automatically` from the top menu to have everything built when you save

You could now get back to the idea where you pass the data from the main report to the subreport just by modifying the main report's subreport declaration to:

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="555" height="398" uuid="3f4fc8a1-d7ff-40ae-b8b3-c5685bf0948e"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("documentList")]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"testsub6.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

No subreport modifications are required.